# How to get data from $router in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have to control the status from users that reach my system by an URL created by one QRCode.

Inside my routes.ts, I'm validating if the user is logged and, then, redirecting the user.

```
if (store.getters.isLogged && to.path === 'QRCode') {
 next();
} else {
     store.dispatch(AUTH_CHECK).then((token) => {
      if (token) {
        next();
      } else {
        Vue.set(router, 'urlQrCode', to.fullPath);
        next('/Login');
      }
    });
}
```

the prop `urlQrCode` does not exist on $router by default

When I'm going to '/Login', I can read 'urlQrCode' from $router (In debug mode) but I can't use this.
Which is the best way to resolve this?

My goal is to go to '/Login' and, after the user connect to the system, redirect him to `to.fullPath`

Comment: As you are already using `vuex` try saving `urlQrCode` in store and access wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in Login.Vue by using the following code:

```
 if (!Validator.isNullUndefinedEmpty((<any>this).$router.urlQrCode)) {
              this.$router.push((<any>this).$router.urlQrCode);
}
```